# Сложность языков

Tags: javascript, java, python, c#, c++

Я не могу нигде найти информацию о том, почему чем сложнее язык, тем он быстрее и круче?
На этот вопрос есть ответ?

Comment: Ответа нет, потому что это утверждение неверно.

Comment: @Goose xD В этот вопрос следует включить больше подробностей и уточнить проблему.

Comment: Круче могут быть только подходы и алгоритмы, но ни один язык не круче другого(и не только в программировании)

Comment: Си и фортран простые и очень быстрые

Comment: У языка нет понятия скорости, это может относиться только в готовым программам, а именно к тому, как в схожих программах, работающих по одному алгоритму, но написанных на разных языках, сравнительно быстро обрабатываются данные. Чем ближе язык к железу - тем он сложнее, а программы на нём быстрее. Но это не на 100% верное утверждение, есть очень много оговорок...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, потому что 1) Это не так. 2) Непонятно, что значит "круче".  И я вовсе не уверен, что например С++ сложнее какого-нибудь Erlang. Или Haskell. Про "крутость" вообще умолчу.

Comment: Языки вокруг которых крутится большое количество программистов почему-то работают так, к примеру те же простые  python и java намного слабее с++

Comment: По сравнению с перечисленными в вопросе языками Erlang - однозначно самый простой.

Comment: Пишу на ErLang серверный софт, подтверждаю, язык простой. Не надо путать сложность освоения языка с сложностью освоения принципов функционального программирования. Да прибудет с вами F# и хвостовая рекурсия. Аминь.